# Spark Cummulative Processing on single log file

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

For log processing using `spark streaming`, I have used `socketStream` and `textFileStream` APIs. Through socketStream, using `nc -lk` on a particular port, we can read the appending log file, and through textFileStream, any new file added in a directory can be read and cummulative processing can be done.

What I am looking is for a **single** log file, which grows with time, how can I read the same log file into say: DStream or any `Spark RDD` handle and then process it cummulatively. I don't intend to use `nc -lk`, as it may not be a general approach. Is there any way or API in Spark, where we can listen to the log file, and any additions to it will be read and processed into `RDD` formats?

Comment: You might want to look into Kafka instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no native APIs in Spark to monitoring the `single` log file and get continuous incremental log content for now(before 1.6 version)
but it seems that netcat pattern(tail and netnet pipeline to receive continous incremental log) is prevalent both in socket stream and Kafka stream.
Using spark socket stream to connect to pipelined netcat.

```
tail -f xxx.log | nc -lk 9999
```

Or Using spark Kafka stream to connect to pipelined kafkacat.

> kafkacat is a generic non-JVM producer and consumer for Apache Kafka
>   0.8, think of it as a netcat for Kafka.

https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | kafkacat -b mybroker -t syslog -z snappy
```

Note:Read messages from stdin, produce to 'syslog' topic with snappy compression.

Comment: using `nc` is a clever way to do this... however, I think i saw somewhere that in 2.0 you can actually monitor a file. but i'm not positive about that. more research required. :)